# Capture response from .jsp

Tags: html, jsp, cron

I am a naive user.

There is this website which is a really important source of information for my business.

To monitor the websites, I convert them to RSS feeds using page2rss service and then monitor feeds in IFTTT.

However, this particular site does not use static web pages and generates data response to API Calls:

Here is a sample API Call:

https://www.mpeproc.gov.in/ROOTAPP/GetTenderFreeView.jsp?Department=Urban%20Administration%20and%20Development%20Department&company=MPSEDC

Is there a way by which I could record the response from this call to an html page on my server? or is there any other way to monitor such dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions but not simple ones. The first page uses JavaScript to create a FORM which it then submits. You can simulate this with the command line tool `curl`; see https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

But take note that many sites don't like scraping; if they notice what you're doing, you may end up on a blacklist. So it's better to ask the site's owner for permission before you aim automated tools at their precious data.

Comment: Let me try you solution.
I understand the concern from the website's point of view. I plan to use this scheme for my own personal use with limited frequency. Thanks :)